# Android - APK disassembler

Tags: android, gdb, apk

I'm trying to get the assembler code executed for an APK. It can be extracted dynamically like `gdb dissas` or statically like `objdump`.

I tried with gdb without any exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using GDB.

Emulator:

gdbserver :5039 --attach pid

PC:

adb forward tcp:5039 tcp:5039

gdb 
    => target remote 127.0.0.1:5039

Now in gdb we can see asm with "layout asm" or EIB ass using "x/i 0xEIB"

Answer (score 0):

[APKs are actually just archives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29), similar to a JAR.

Within an APK you will find a number of files with application metadata (such as a manifest and certificate information), along with resource files and source files. The source code within an APK are also not Assembly files; they are [DEX files for the Dalvik VM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEX_%28file_format%29).

You will not find Assembly in an APK.

Comment: You might find assembly if the APK includes a native library.  The DEX file format is specified at http://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html .  You can disassemble it with the "dexdump" tool, included with the SDK and on some devices, or use something fancy like baksmali.